# Matching one or another word in AngularJS ui-router

Tags: regex, angularjs

Using AngularJS + ui-router, I need to match a url with one of two words:

i.e. `/oneWord/...` or `/secondWord`...

The routing and controllers are nearly identical, so I want to avoid duplicating code.

However, using a regex I'm used to, doesn't work where regular expressions should work:

`url: '/{type:(oneWord|secondWord)}/:group',`

However, it throws an error:

`Unbalanced capture group in route '/{type:(oneWord|secondWord)}/:group'`

A regex should work though, because this works fine:

`url: "/{page:[0-9]{1,8}}"`

I know that `(oneWord|secondWord)` is a valid regex, so what have I missed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#wiki-regex-parameters) you should not use capturing parentheses in your regex patterns.

This should work: `url: '/{type:(?:oneWord|secondWord)}/:group'`

Comment: I completely missed that, I even read that just the other day. Thanks. Will accept answer when the site allows me.

Comment: Any suggestions, on the regex if the second word is null? Can it be `url: '/{type:(?:oneWord|null)}/:group'`

Comment: what will be the regex for a parameter  that should not match with `oneWord` ?